# Python EasyGUI fileopenbox() filter more items

Tags: python, easygui, fileopenpicker

I want to set EasyGUI `fileopenbox()` to filter more filetypes and not just one.

Here below is a code I tried but instead of [custom files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dijrF.png) selection i get [more selections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aKrK.png).

```
file=easygui.fileopenbox(title='Select image', filetypes=('*.png', '*.jpg'))
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#easygui.fileopenbox)

> About the “filetypes” argument
>
> If specified, it should contain a list of items, where each item is
> either:
>
> - a string containing a filemask # e.g. “*.txt”
> - a list of strings, where
>   all of the strings except the last one are filemasks (each beginning
>   with “*.”, such as “*.txt” for text files, “*.py” for Python files,
>   etc.). and the last string contains a filetype description
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> `filetypes = ["*.css", ["*.htm", "*.html", "HTML files"]  ]`

So corresponding to your usecase, you can write:

```
file=easygui.fileopenbox(title='Select image', filetypes=[["*.png", "*.jpg", "Image files"]])
```